# c# How do you thread a recursive directory search?

Tags: c#, recursion, getdirectories

I'm trying to thread this below function so that the background form can continue to be moved around and won't 'freeze', can anyone assist me in doing this?

```
    public IEnumerable<string> GetFiles(string path) 
    {
        Queue<string> queue = new Queue<string>();
        queue.Enqueue(path);
        while (queue.Count > 0)
        {
            path = queue.Dequeue();
            try
            {
                foreach (string subDir in Directory.GetDirectories(path))
                {
                    queue.Enqueue(subDir);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                richTextBox1.AppendText(ex.Message);
            }
            string[] files = null;
            try
            {
                files = Directory.GetFiles(path);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                richTextBox1.AppendText(ex.Message);
            }
            if (files != null)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++)
                {
                    yield return files[i];
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I execute the code with the following button:

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int count = 0;
        FolderBrowserDialog dialog = new FolderBrowserDialog();
        dialog.ShowDialog();
        string selected = dialog.SelectedPath;

        foreach (string file in GetFiles(selected))
        {
            count++;
            richTextBox1.AppendText(file + Environment.NewLine);

        }
        label2.Text = count.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: Is this winforms or wpf?

Comment: @SliverNinja: When did WPF use the standard `EventHandler`?  ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put the whole thing into a background thread (possibly with `BackgroundWorker`, possibly with `Task` in .NET 4) and use `Control.Invoke` or `Control.BeginInvoke` to marshal back to the UI thread when you want to update the UI.

You won't be able to just call `GetFiles` and use the result in the UI - at least until C# 5, which will make all this a lot easier with async/await - but you can make the background thread "tell" the UI thread when it's completed - and also when it's found each individual file. Basically, abandon the iterator block, and either keep `count` as state within the class, or get the background thread to report the total count when it calls back to the UI thread when it's finished.

Comment: Jon, excuse my ignorance but I'm not very well versed on threading, would you perhaps be able to offer up additional information or perhaps an example using my existing code base? Thank you.

Comment: @user995820: If you search for resources on `Control.Invoke` and `Control.BeginInvoke` you'll find *lots* of examples. The code you've posted is quite complex and would take a while to convert, but you quite possibly want to have an `AddMessage` method which conditionally calls `textBox1.BeginInvoke` - it should use `textBox1.InvokeRequired` to see whether it needs to do that.

Comment: Jon, great, thank you for all of the information, much appreciated.